# Migrating Data from Dynamics environment to another Dynamics environment Using Azure Data Factory

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

I am trying to copy data from dynamics to dynamics; we have a SQL DB for the source dynamics environment. I have connected to that DB via SSMS, and I am doing all the transformations and creating views in SSMS, after that I am linking them to the pipeline and pushing data to the destination environment. Pipelines were working fine till 23 May 2022, and suddenly, I was getting this error in one of my pipelines.

> ErrorCode=DynamicsOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Dynamics
> operation failed with error code: -2147220956, error message: Sequence
> contains no
> elements.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.DynamicsPlugin,''Type=System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault,
> Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]],Message=The creator of this fault
> did not specify a
> Reason.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.DynamicsPlugin,'

Not sure what I am missing. I am assuming that while importing data, some columns have null values, but I had some null values before, and it was working fine. Any thoughts on how to resolve this issue will be great.
This is the SQL statement for creating a view

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you ever come across this kind of issue in dynamics. Please check the workflow and plugins that are related to that entity. In my scenario there was a plugin which was on contact entity and it was faulty and I  switched off that plugin and the pipeline started working

switch of the plugins first and turn them on one by one and you can figure out which plugin was faulty.